# phpmailer has issues with long messages

Tags: php, forms, gmail, phpmailer

I have a form in PHP and i am using PHPmailer to sent it to my gmail account.
recently i had several problems with messages in hebrew, and i got scrambled messages in my inbox [attached example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z8lA.png).
i now suspect it is an issue of length, but i couldnt find the limit or the reason for the limit.
**ONly the hebrew gets scramled! english remains the same.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$email      = 'myname@gmail.com';
$subject    = 'New Point Added';
$from       = "autosender@mywebsite";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $msg  = "שם המטייל/ת:<br> ".$_POST['hiker']."<br />";
            $msg .= "מדינה: <br>".$_POST['country']."<br />";
            $msg .= "חודש ושנה:<br> ".$_POST['dob']."<br />";
            $msg .= "סוג:<br> ".$_POST['point']."<br />";
            $msg .= "שם המקום:<br> ".$_POST['place']."<br />";
            $msg .= "תיאור:<br> ".$_POST['description']."<br />";
            $msg .= "מחיר:<br> ".$_POST['price']."<br />";
            $msg .= "איך להגיע:<br> ".$_POST['howtoget']."<br />";
            $msg .= "חוויות אישיות:<br> ".$_POST['personalexp']."<br />";
            $msg .= "מיקום במפה:<br> ".$_POST['latitude']."";
            $msg .= ",".$_POST['longitude']."<br />";
                        $headers = "From: $from" . "\r";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1";
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->From      = $from;
            $mail->FromName  = $from;
            $mail->Subject   = $subject;
            $mail->Body      = $msg;
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->headers = $headers;
            if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
                $file_to_attach = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                $mail->AddAttachment($file_to_attach , $_POST['hiker'].'-'.date('U').'-'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
            }

            $mail->Send();
            //mail($email,$subject,$msg,$headers);
            ?>
```

Comment: have you tried utf-8 its becoming the standard.

Comment: yes my previus version was UTF-8 and it didnt work as well...

Comment: You don't set headers like that in PHPMailer - read the docs! View source on the message you receive and you'll see it's doing it for you already.

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're using [the latest version of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

Well Hebrew will *definitely* not work in ISO-8859-1, and the text you're putting in there will be corrupted, just as you're seeing. PHPMailer defaults to ISO-8859-1, and you *must* tell it if you're using something else. **Use UTF-8**, and make sure that the data you're passing in is actually UTF-8, and not some other Hebrew charset, like ISO-8859-8. Use UTF-8 as the charset in your HTML, and set PHPMailer to use UTF-8 as its charset too, like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```